# Open multiple SAS windows for multiple programs

Tags: python, sas, saspy

I have 3 sas program like:-
a.sas, b.sas, c.sas

So if I click on a.sas, a sas session/window will open, then
if I click on b.sas, a different sas session/window should open and if I click on c.sas again, then a third sas session/window should open.

So I can run these sas programs simultaneously.

Please help me in achieving it.
Also can it be possible with saspy in python?

Comment: What do you mean by "click on"?  Are you using Windows? Is SAS installed locally on the Windows machine?  Why not just open a command line window and type three commands. `sas a`, `sas b` and `sas c`.

Comment: Why is the python tag included?

Comment: Do you have a SAS/CONNECT license? You can do this from SAS in a SAS program using SYSTASK and the Windows command to execute a program. It will set all three to run immediately.  SAS/Connect makes it a bit easier but this way works as well. https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/hostwin/p09xs5cudl2lfin17t5aqvpcxkuz.htm

Comment: And if you have Viya you should have access to batch/scheduling tools that are GUI based so why do it this way at all?